# ASMCMD doesn't return any result

Tags: oracle, oracle-asm, oracle-grid-control

I'm trying to use ASMCMD but it doesn't return any result in the command line

```
ASMCMD> ls
ASMCMD>
ASMCMD>
ASMCMD>
ASMCMD> lsdg
ASMCMD>
ASMCMD> pwd
ASMCMD>
```

The version of database is 19c, the only environment about oracle grid is the `GRID_HOME`, but I also have the `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_BASE`, currently my `$ORACLE_SID` is `orcl` and my `$ORACLE_HOME` is `/u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1`.

My output about `srvctl config asm` is:

```
ASM home: <CRS home>
Password file: +DATA/orapwasm
Backup of Password file:
ASM listener: LISTENER,LISTENER2
Spfile: +DATA/ASM/ASMPARAMETERFILE/registry.253.1011650339
ASM diskgroup discovery string: /dev/oracleasm/disks/*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incorrect environment. `ORACLE_HOME` for grid should be pointing to grid directory and `ORACLE_SID` for ASM should be +ASM.

Try this:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=$GRID_HOME
export $ORACLE_SID=+ASM
export PATH=$GRID_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

– [Kumar](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/168186/kumar)